# Pagination Concept in Django & efficient way to implement over large objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

While learning Django Concepts, I Came across the pagination concept at: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/`

I understand that pagination is used for rendering the object fields of the model into discrete pages.

In the documentation, the Author provided the following snippet that :

`contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25)`

Which is basically loading all objects of model `Contacts` and putting them into pagination to limit the per page size to 25.

My Question here is: Imagine we have thousands of objects under `Contacts` model with large TextField, doing `Contacts.objects.all()` will take some time, In this situation what would be the best efficient way to implement pagination such that pagination happens over `Contacts.objects` instead of loading all and then passing to Paginator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django `Paginator` (`django.core.paginator.Paginator`) class uses a slice on queryset, which is run as a `LIMIT` query on database, so it does not get all the instances and then get the subset, rather it only retrieves the subset from databse using `LIMIT`. In case of offset, it uses `LIMIT <> OFFSET <>`, so that's efficient as well.

Django querysets are lazy, so when you do `Contacts.objects.all()` and pass  it to the paginator, it is not evaluated then -- it will be evaluated later when the paginator actually tries to slice it to get the required number of elements for a given page.